# Access Integer Value From Another Class in java

Tags: java, class, variables, integer

how accesing a int in my public class to my class? dor example I declare a int with a value in public class and access it in my class in java.
so I want to access int jumlah in class node, precisely in void displayLink
[image: so I want to access int jumlah in class node, precisely in void displayLink]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

To use variables of other classes without a reference you have to declare these variables as static. For example you have a public class called "Alien" and you want to get the size:

```
public class Alien {
     public static final int size = 82;
}
```

In order to now get the size you have to call `Alien.size`

You can also create a reference to the alien class:

```
Alien alien = new Alien();
```

Using this method the variables don't need to be static only public. You can get the size by calling: `alien.size`

EDIT: added final tag :)

Comment: Guess you will fail any code review or job interview with that approach. A `public static` without `final` is a no-no in any reasonable OO design. Same for public instance variables!